# How to create a c# enumeration with more than one property

Tags: c#, .net, class, enumeration

I want to create an enumeration like object but with an additional "property".

For example I could have a day of the week enumeration:

```
enum Day {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
```

Now, let's say I have another property I want to store against each day. Something that never changes. For the sake of the argument let's say we have a pay rate which never changes and is 1.5 on Saturday, 2 on Sunday and 1 otherwise.

Can't do this with enumeration. I was thinking of creating a "helper" static class that would just return this second property, but this seems clunky.

```
static class Rate
{
    static float GetRate(Day d)
    {
        switch (d)
        {
            case Day.Saturday:
                return 1.5f;
            case Day.Sunday:
                return 2f;
            default:
                return 1f;

        }
    }
}
```

Instead of enum with helper class I could use a ReadOnlyCollection but that seems complicated and heavy-weight for what I need.

What is the best way to go here?

Comment: what about a keyvalue pair? or a dictionary?

Comment: your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @ViVi these are not constant/read-only

Comment: You need some key-value-pair-logic, for example a List of `KeyValuePair`, or essentially a `Dictionary`. You could also create your own class for this or as you already did a method returning the property for a given enum-value.

Comment: I'm with @TaW. Just make the current method an extension method, so you can use it more naturally.

Comment: If it works but you are not sure if it's the proper way to do it, you should ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. Opinion based questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# enum values are simple single-values unlike in other languages where they can be complex-types (e.g. tuples).

If the enum value represents a "key" for immutable data, you could hack it by using an extension method with a `switch` block - similar to your example, but syntactically cleaner when used:

```
enum Day {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };

public static class DayExtensions
{
    public static Single GetRate(this Day d)
    {
        switch( d )
        {
            case Day.Saturday:
                return 1.5f;
            case Day.Sunday:
                return 2f;
            default:
                return 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Day d = Day.Monday;
Single rate = d.GetRate();
```

Comment: This is in fact a very common way to extend enum functionality. You keep the extension class in the same source code file as the enum, because they are logically part of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is add a custom attribute to the enum values like so:

```
enum Day {
    [MyAttr(Rate=1.5f)]
    Sunday, 
    [MyAttr(Rate=2)]
    Monday
}

public class MyAttr : Attribute {
    public float Rate {get;set;}
}
```

Then read the attribute like this:

```
public float GetRate(Day day) {
    MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(Day).GetMember(day.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

    if (memberInfo != null) {
        MyAttr attribute = (MyAttr)memberInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttr), false)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return attribute.Rate;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
public struct Day
{
    public Day(int key, float rate)
    {
        _key = key;
        _rate = rate;
    }
    private readonly int _key;
    private readonly float _rate;
    public int Key => _key;
    public float Rate => _rate;

    public static readonly Day
        Monday = new Day(0, 1f),
        Tuesday = new Day(0, 1f), ...;

    public static implicit operator int(Day day) => day.Key;
}
```

Then `Day.Monday.Rate` works, and `int day = Day.Monday` works.

Comment: Why have both readonly private fields and public properties simultaneously?

Comment: @Dai feel free to adjust locally to suit etc :)

Comment: @Dai You cannot have a `readonly` property. The `readonly` keyword garantuees that the value of the field cannot be modified outside of the constructor.

Comment: @Maarten C# 6.0 introduced true readonly properties using the `public PropertyName { get; }` syntax, which uses a `readonly` backing field.

Comment: @Dai I think you mean C# 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sealed class with predefined static instances. The extra property (or properties) can be read either as property, or via implicit conversion.

```
public sealed class Day
{
    private Day(float rate)
    {
        m_Rate = rate;
    }

    private readonly float m_Rate;
    public float Rate { get { return m_Rate; } }

    public static readonly Day Saturday = new Day(1.5f);
    public static readonly Day Sunday = new Day(2f);
    public static readonly Day Monday = new Day(1f);
    public static readonly Day Tuesday = new Day(1f);
    public static readonly Day Wednesday = new Day(1f);
    public static readonly Day Thursday = new Day(1f);
    public static readonly Day Friday = new Day(1f);

    public static implicit operator float(Day day)
    {
        return day.m_Rate;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var day = Day.Sunday;
var rate = day.Rate;      // Use property
float rate2 = day;        // Use implicit conversion
```